# Get the word using first letter in a string

Tags: ios, objective-c

Example of what I am trying to do:

```
String = "2 A2 E10 string"
```

**E10 is not fixed**. it may be `E222` 0r `E1` but starting letter **E is fixed**.

I am looking to get this as a result: `"E10"`

I am struggling with objective-c and strings for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure that there are words like "2", "A2" and "E10" in the string separated by whitespaces and you want the last string, you can use,

```
NSString *string = @"2 A2 E10";
NSArray *words = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSString *lastWord = [words lastObject];
```